# What Is The Difference Between Pub/Sub And jQuery Data-Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

A popular topic at the jQuery conference in Boston this month was the idea of Pub/Sub - 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2037-Simple-Publication-And-Subscription-Functionality-Pub-Sub-With-jQuery.htm

A common example of what one may use PubSub to do is tracking for a piece of data changing value in order to execute some other event. As far as I know this can be done using either jQuery or the jQuery Data-Link plugin without requiring a PubSub architecture of your own.

What I would like to know is, what exactly are the differences between what PubSub has to offer and what simple data-binding does?.

Is it perhaps more efficient performance wise?

Answer (score 2):

They are 2 separate beasts.

PubSub offers a way to maintain a pool of subscribers/notifications on a page. In other words, let's say you have 2 components on a page. Comp A publishes an event. Comp B is listening to the event. This way, they are decoupled from each others implementation and talk via messages (event args/data). Comp B can completely ignore the event or may choose to even not subscribe to it or it can react to the event and take further action.

jQuery Data Link is an automatic way of keeping data synchronized between 2 or more elements. Let's say you have 2 input elements on page. And you want the value of one to change whenever someone changes the value in the other one. For example, the other field might be a 'total' field and you want its value to be updated as soon as someone changes the first input's value.

Hope this helps.